# Скачать файл из MS Server - java (spring)

Tags: java, веб-программирование, spring, файлы

Есть база на MS Server, в ней таблица со структурой:

```
idFile (int)
fileName (varchar)
file (varbinary)
```

Веб-приложение на java со спрингом. Какой тип в Entity прописать для file? И как в последующем сделать так, чтобы можно было бы скачать файл пользователю?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Спасибо за подсказку с byte[]
Вот так выглядит поле в Entity

```
private byte[] fileLoad;
```

Вот такая функция поможет скачать файл с сайта:

```
@GetMapping("/download")
    public ResponseEntity<ByteArrayResource> getFile(Model model, @RequestParam String file) {
        try {
            MyFiles fileDown;
            //find file
            return ResponseEntity.ok()
                    .header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION, "attachment; filename=\"" + fileDown .getFileName() + "\"")
                    .body(new ByteArrayResource(fileDown .getFile()));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            //TODO smt
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Согласно [таблице](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/using-basic-data-types?view=sql-server-ver15)

```
varbinary - SQL Server Types    
VARBINARY - JDBC Types (java.sql.Types)
```

конвертируется в `byte[]` в java